# Is LINQ-to-SQL available in metro style apps on Windows 8?

Tags: linq-to-sql, windows-8, microsoft-metro

I'm porting a Windows Phone 7 app to work for Windows 8 (and take advantage of the new form factors available).

There appears to be [a handy namespace map](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465136%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) for a lot of the namespaces, and there are some that are explicitly called out as not avaialbe, but there appears to be no mention of LINQ-to-SQL - is this an omission in the documentation, or is it not available in metro style applications?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LINQ-to-SQL and LINQ-to-Entities are not available in Metro-style apps. Metro-style apps are meant to be lightweight apps which can retrieve data from web services (generally running in the cloud).

Thus, ADO.NET and the entire `System.Data` namespace is not supported.

Comment: ADO.Net isn't exposed on Windows Phone devices, but LINQ-to-SQL is still available. It seems wrong that I can do more on a phone (that will share the same core OS from the next release), than on a Pc or tablet; It also seems bad that I cannot cache for disconnected scenarios

Comment: You can use a file cache for disconnected scenarios - by serialising objects to XML/JSON/Binary using the Windows.Storage APIs. You might want to take a look at : http://winrtstoragehelper.codeplex.com/

Comment: @RowlandShaw yes, Microsoft politics is very irritating. They still didn't add Local Database in Windows 8.x.

Answer (score 0):

Mention was made in the Windows Phone Summit on Wednesday that SQLLite would be available on WP8 and Win8, but no details as to the programming API's were shared yet. Currently the Metro subset of .Net for WinRT applications does not include a database API set. There are some independant efforts to port some of the no-sql based implementations, including RhynoDB and Sterling, so you may want to keep your ears open to further announcements.